Type 'Row' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, (string | number | boolean | Date)[]>'
Type 'Row' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, (string | number | boolean | Date)[]>'.
Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Row'.
59 |   componentDidUpdate() {
60 |     if (this.table) {

61 |       this.table.update([DataManipulator.generateRow(this.props.data)]);
|                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
62 |
63 |        }
64 |   }

how to remove this error
